# Close createWebsocketStream without closing the websocket connection (node, ws)

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I have been testing sending files over websocket from a client to server using the [createWebsocketStream function from ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#createwebsocketstreamwebsocket-options) like so:

```
client                                    server
readFileStream ---> WebSocketStream ---> writeFileStream
```

It works insomuch as I can send even large files successfully, but when I try to close the duplex on the client side, it closes the whole websocket connection.

On the server-side, the WebsocketStream doesn't emit a `close` event so I can't signal based on that.

So I have two problems:

- I can't start and end a duplex websocketstream on the same persistent websocket connection. To workaround this I fork a new websocket connection for streaming properties, but this kind of feels like a hack. If I understand correctly, this is because the duplex is a wrapper *around* the ws connection and is by design, but I would appreciate a sanity check on that.
- The websocketstream doesn't emit a `close` event so I can't signal the filewrite stream to end based on that.

Is this by design? Is it not possible to start and end a duplex stream on the same ws connection?

If it helps, here is what I have working: I end the writeFileStream based on a ws connection closure:

### server:

```js
//server.js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');
const wsserver = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

const destinationFileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./bar');

wsserver.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log("client connected");
  duplex = WebSocket.createWebSocketStream(ws);
  duplex.on('data', function(data){
    destinationFileStream.write(data);
  });
  duplex.on('close', function(){ //<----------i want to put it here but this never triggers
    console.log("the duplex channel has closed")
  });

  ws.on('close', function(){
    console.log("websocket has closed")
    destinationFileStream.end(); //<----------instead I have to put it here :(
  });
  destinationFileStream.on('close', function(){
    console.log("file has been written successfully")
  })
});
```

### client:

```
//client.js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');
// connect to the server for normal communication
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
const readFileStream = fs.createReadStream('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/atom-amd64.deb')

ws.on('open', function(){
  // fork a NEW connection called wsstream with duplex properties so we can maintain a normal message channel here
  var wsstream = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
  var duplex = WebSocket.createWebSocketStream(wsstream, { emitClose: true });
  readFileStream.on('data', function(data){
  console.log('reading file stream')
  duplex.write(data);
  });
  readFileStream.on('close', function(){
    console.log("file has been read successfully")
    duplex.end(); // <--- this triggers the wsstream.on('close') function
  });
  duplex.on('close', function(){ // <- this never fires because there's no close event
    console.log("the duplex channel has closed") 
  });
  wsstream.on('close', function(){
    console.log("the wsstream has closed") // <-- closing the duplex channel closes the whole wsstream connection
  });
// more functions below for the regular ws connection
});
```

p.s. sorry for code quality! I only started learning last week.